# VMWare-Player downward compatibility?

Tags: vmware-player

I used VMware-Player version 4.0.4 on one Pc. The other Pc has version 3.x installed.

Transferring files from version 4 to version 3 fails, because there are different features used.

I can not update it to version 4.0.4 for the reason of a problematic error, which seems to occur often, but there seems to be no clear solution. Updating to version 5.0 fails, because it would need an update for glibc...

The question is: Can I use VMware-Player version 4.0.4 to create files, that are usable with version 3.x ?

Answer (score 0):

Use VMware VCenter Converter to downgrade your VM (the VMX file is really what you're updating!)
Its free, and works pretty good.

Comment: No, this *up*grades the VM. It doesn't *down*grade it.